# C# Multithreading conflicts on shared variables

Tags: c#, multithreading, thread-safety

My Problem is the following:
I've got a GUI running in its own thread 1 setting some configuration settings.

The configuration itself will be used (only Read access) by another thread 2 in different classes, but when i apply in my GUI it should be updated as fast as possible.

The configuration contains variables like bool and Dictionaries.

What would be a safe way to realize this problem?

My thoughts so far:
A class containing the current configuration in some static Instance variable:

```
public class Config
{
   static Config Instance;
   int a;
   Dictionary<int, int> b;
   ...
   public void update(Config newConfig) {}
}
```

so all classes in Thread 2 can always access the newest settings.

An update function is called, when i press something like an "apply"-Button in the GUI to apply the newest settings.

But what about thread safety? How to set the variables only when thread2 isn't reading and make thread 2 waiting when variables are set? I don't have any experience with multithreading in c# and i know it probably have to lock up the variables while used by some thread. or is there some other smart approach how to realize it?

Comment: When in doubt, lock it. If you're even considering whether or not to lock... just lock. When reading or writing, lock your shared state. That said, there are a lot of possible ways to attack this problem, and multithreading/shared state is a fairly deep topic, so I'd say this question is over broad.

Answer (score 0):

If you have one shared instance of `Config` and everything uses that instance, then there's a risk that other threads could change properties while you're reading them. To prevent that you could `lock` access to individual properties. But it's not a pleasant thought. Instead it's better to minimize the occasions when you have to worry about that.

One step would be to have your other threads create new instances of `Config` instead of all of them sharing. That your GUI (a form?) can receive an entirely new instance of `Config`.

If you have something like this (just for example - whether a property should be public or how your class *receives* an instance of `Config` is a whole different question.)

```
public Config MyConfigInstance { get; set; }
```

If you set that property by supplying a different instance of `Config` with different values, that's an atomic operation. You don't have to worry that your class will access `MyConfigInstance` halfway through the reference being updated.

That might be all you need. But there's still room for error. Now your class has a reference to a new instance of `Config`. But what other threads have access to that same reference, and can still change it? At the very least the thread that passed it to this class still has access. What if that thread passes that instance around and now other classes have references to it?

That might not be an issue in your application. Maybe you know exactly what threads have access to instances of which classes. But if something gets more complex, again we'd rather head off the problem than try to keep track of it.

To that end, if multiple threads will share instances of a class, it's often preferable to make the class immutable. That's something like this:

```
public class MyImmutableClass
{
    public MyImmutableClass(string stringValue, int intValue)
    {
        StringValue = stringValue;
        IntValue = intValue;
    }

    public string StringValue { get; }
    public int IntValue { get; }
}
```

Its properties are set when it's created and can't be changed. At this point you don't care how many threads have references to an instance of the class because none of them can change it. You can replace a reference to one instance with a reference to a new instance, but that won't affect other references.

Another benefit of an immutable class is that if the values are only set in the constructor, then you can validate them. Like in the above example you could throw an exception if `stringValue` is null. That way you always know that the class is in a valid state. It's impossible to create an instance that's in an invalid state.

We tend to create mutable classes because it's quicker to create read/write properties than it is to create a constructor. But if we're going to be passing instances around to different threads then it's sometimes preferable to start with immutability, which forces us to think about and control what can or can't be done by multiple threads.

Answer (score -1):

You are looking for the singleton design pattern:

```
public sealed class Config
{
    private static Config instance = null;
    private static readonly object padlock = new object();

    #region ConfigProperties
    //put public properties here to represent config values
    public int a { get; set; }
    public Dictionary<int, int> b { get; set; }
    #endregion ConfigProperties

    Config()
    {
        ReadConfig();
    }

    public static Config Instance
    {
        get
        {
            lock (padlock)
            {
                if (instance == null)
                {
                    instance = new Config();
                }
                return instance;
            }
        }
    }
    public void ReadConfig()
    {
        //read from your config file and set properties
    }
    public void SaveConfig()
    {
        //write properties back into your config file
    }
}
```

This class is thread safe, meaning that you can use `Config.Instance.` followed by any of your config properties, and they will be safely accessed without causing cross-thread issues.

There are more elegant solutions and more at-length explanations [here](http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/General/Singleton.aspx).